# linq query order help

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, json.net

the following action method returns json data to my jqGrid as described in this article:
[using-jquery-grid-with-asp.net-mvc](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/14/using-jquery-grid-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx)

my question is based on this linq query:

```
    var data = (
    from job in jobs
    select new
    {
      id = job.Id,
      cell = new List<string>() { job.Industry, job.OccupationName }
    }).ToArray();
```

Why are the cell list entries not ordered as expected? (Industry followed by OccupationName) :

What I expect is:

---

```
{"total":1400,"page":1,"records":7000,
"rows":[
{"id":"1","cell":{"Industry":"IT","OccupationName":"Administrator"}},
{"id":"2","cell":{"Industry":"IT","OccupationName":"Developer"}},
{"id":"4","cell":{"Industry":"IT","OccupationName":"Programmer"}}
]}
```

---

what i get is:

---

```
{"total":1400,"page":1,"records":7000,
"rows":[
{"id":"1","cell":{"Industry":"IT","OccupationName":"Administrator"}},
{"id":"2","cell":{"Industry":"Developer","OccupationName":"IT"}},
{"id":"4","cell":{"Industry":"IT","OccupationName":"Programmer"}}
]}
```

---

Thanks for any suggestions!

For clarity the whole action method:

```
    public ActionResult OccupationList(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
    {
        using (var context = Service.EF.GetContext())
        {
            int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
            int pageSize = rows;
            int totalRecords = context.sOccupations.Count();
            int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);

            sidx = "it.[" + sidx + "]";

            var jobs = context.sOccupations
                .OrderBy(sidx + " " + sord)
                .Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
                .Take(pageSize);

            var data = (
                  from job in jobs
                  select new
                  {
                      id = job.Id,
                      cell = new List<string>() { job.Industry, job.OccupationName }
                  }).ToArray();

            var jsonData = new
            {
                total = totalPages,
                page = page,
                records = totalRecords,
                rows = data
            };

            return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

My current solution is a classic foreach statement-
but I'm still wondering how to express this as a linq query

```
    IList<JsonRow> data = new List<JsonRow>();
    JsonRow jsonRow;
    foreach (var item in jobs)
    {
        jsonRow = new JsonRow();
        jsonRow.id = item.Id;
        jsonRow.cell = new string[2] { item.Industry, item.OccupationName };
        data.Add(jsonRow);
    }

    class JsonRow
    {
        public Guid id { get; set; }
        public string[] cell { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure your data is correct?

Comment: Yes, data are correct :)

Answer (score 3):

You'd have to order the "cell" as you like.

```
 var data = (
        from job in jobs
orderby job.OccupationName
        select new
        {
          id = job.Id,
          cell = new List<string>() { job.Industry, job.OccupationName }
        }).ToArray();
```

You will have to check the syntax, since I haven't tried to run it yet.
Edit: I tried this, it should work.

Comment: No luck right now. The dynamic link query above the statement works fine. It collects data based on the grid parameters.   The linq query should only create an anonymous type based on the filtered data.

Comment: You could always try breaking the query in to 2. Have the first part (before the select new) as one statement, then do the transformation in a second query. Sometimes I find this helps me find errors in my logic that aren't always apparent when trying to do it all as a single query.